# how to make changing link upload_to imagefield in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

in my product model there is a category field, it refers to another table, in the category table there is a title field, I would like each image to be saved in a folder with the name of the corresponding category__title

```
class ProductImage(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='...')
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name='title', unique=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `upload_to`:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to

paths.py

```
def upload_product_image(instance, filename):
    # instance is ProductImage object
    # here whatever we want.
    return f"{instance.product.category.title}/{filename}"
```

models.py

```
from .paths import upload_product_image

class ProductImage(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_product_image)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import os

def image_upload_path(instance, filename):
    # Get the category title for the current product image
    category_title = instance.product.category.title
    # Join the category title with the filename to create the final path
    upload_path = os.path.join('product_images', category_title, filename)
    return upload_path

class ProductImage(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=image_upload_path)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```